# 4 Vector2 points to top left top right bottom left bottom right

Tags: c#, xna

I have 4 Vector2 in a list and I want to sort them to

```
Vector2 topleft
Vector2 topright
Vector2 bottomleft
Vector2 bottomright
```

I have tried by comparing the distance but had no success.
I would like a fast way that solves my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put the vectors inside an array and create a comparer method now you can sort the array on base of your own comparer method:

```
     public Vector2[] directions=new Vector2[4];// put your vectors here


     void Sort() 
     {
      Array.Sort(directions, Vector2Compare);    
     }


     private int Vector2Compare(Vector2 value1, Vector2 value2)
     {
         // NOTE: THESE DEPENDS ON HOW YOU EVALUATE TOP/LEFT/RIGHT/BOTTOM , X and Y  
         if (value1.x < value2.x)
         {
             return -1;
         }
         else if(value1.x == value2.x)
         {
             if(value1.y < value2.y)
             {
                 return -1;
             }
             else if(value1.y == value2.y)
             {
                 return 0;
             }
             else
             {
                 return 1;
             }
         }
         else
         {
             return 1;
         }
     }
```